# Angular Loop Syntax

Tags: angular

What is the syntax for looping an array to print out additional `<li>` markup inside a `<ul>`. I'm using angular 4.

I have tried:

```
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <ng-template *ngFor="let p of arr">
    <li>{{p}}</li>
  </ng-template>
  <li>Last</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just drop the `ng-template` and use the `ngFor` inside an `li` tag

```
<ul>
  <li>First</li>  
  <li *ngFor="let p of arr">{{p}}</li>
  <li>Last</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Or replace `ng-template` with `ng-container`. Or `<ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="arr" let-p>`

Comment: Thanks, i didn't see it working like that, i thought that the array would be printed out in a single li.